# Getting wrong warning in Dart (possible bug), (The operand can't be null, so the condition is always 'true'.)

Tags: dart, intellij-idea, warnings

Here is my Dart program:

```
void main() {
  bool? b;
  if(b==true){
    print('b is true');
  }else if(b==false){
    print('b is false');
  }else if(b==null){
    print('b is null');
  }else{
    print('nothing!');
  }
}
```

it outputs this as expected:

`b is null`

but for line,

```
else if(b==null)
```

it's showing this warning:

```
The operand can't be null, so the condition is always 'true'.
```

[image: warning image]

but operand 'b' can be null in the program, as 'b' is nullable(bool?), so it shouldn't show the warning.

it's showing the warning in both IntelliJ IDEA and in https://dartpad.dev/

looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Yes, this is a bug in the error message.  It should be that the operand is *always* null.  This is https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/53670.

Answer (score 1):

if i add little more code like this, the warning is goes away:

```
import 'dart:io';
void main() {
  bool? b;  
  String? input  = stdin.readLineSync();
  if(input=='t'){
    b=true;
  }else if(input=='f'){
    b=false;
  }else{
    //no step
  }  
  if(b==true){
    print('b is true');
  }else if(b==false){
    print('b is false');
  }else if(b==null){
    print('b is null');
  }else{
    print('nothing!');
  }
}
```